# Looking for OPA2227 SPICE model

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice

I did not find this op-amp in LTspice and also I could not find a library for it on Google.
Can someone help me find it?

[image]

Comment: I edited this question based on the assumption that you are looking for the spice model. If you needed something different let me know and I'll change it.

Comment: @GodJihyo Thank you

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [data sheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa2227.pdf?ts=1655144566353&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F), you'll see that the OPA227 (three numbers i.e. 227) is equivalent: -

[image]

And, in my simulator, the spice model for the 227 is this: -

```
.SUBCKT OPA227 3 2 7 4 6
* FEATURES MODELED ARE
* OPEN LOOP GAIN AND PHASE
* INPUT VOLTAGE NOISE W 1/F
* INPUT CURRENT NOISE W 1/F
* INPUT BIAS CURRENT
* INPUT CAPACITANCE
* INPUT COMMON MODE VOLT RANGE
* INPUT DIFFERENTIAL CLAMPS
* CMRR WITH FREQUENCY EFFECTS
* PSRR WITH FREQUENCY EFFECTS
* SLEW RATE
* QUIESCENT CURRENT
* QUIESCENT CURRENT VS VOLTAGE
* OUTPUT CURRENT THROUGH SUPPLIES
* OUTPUT CURRENT LIMITING
* OUTPUT CLAMPS TO RAILS
* OUTPUT SWING VS OUTPUT CURRENT
* END OF FEATURES
Q26 8 9 10 QON
Q27 11 9 12 QOP
Q28 4 13 14 QOP
Q29 7 15 16 QON
I4 8 15 3E-3
I5 13 11 3E-3
R34 17 16 1
R35 14 17 1
C6 9 18 40E-12
R36 18 9 1E3
G1 9 18 19 0 -1E-3
G2 20 18 21 22 -0.5E-2
R37 18 20 1E10
C7 19 23 115E-12
R38 19 20 1.5E3
E1 24 18 19 18 1
D2 24 20 DD
R39 18 23 50
Q30 22 25 26 QIN
Q31 21 27 28 QIN
Q32 29 30 31 QN
R40 11 31 4.499E3
V6 30 32 1.2613
R41 22 33 220
R42 21 33 220
V7 8 34 2
R45 29 26 1
R46 29 28 1
R47 6 17 10
D1 34 33 DD
D3 20 24 DD
D4 35 8 DD
D5 11 36 DD
V8 35 20 1.6
V9 20 36 1.1
E6 37 0 8 0 1
E7 38 0 11 0 1
E8 39 0 40 0 1
R48 37 41 100E6
R49 38 42 100E6
R50 39 43 1000E6
R51 0 41 100
R52 0 42 100
R53 0 43 100
E11 44 3 43 0 0.7
R54 45 40 1E3
R55 40 46 1E3
C10 37 41 1E-9
C11 38 42 1E-9
C12 39 43 1E-12
E12 47 44 42 0 0.3
E13 48 47 41 0 0.3
R60 47 48 1E9
R61 44 47 1E9
R62 3 44 1E9
E22 45 0 2 0 1
E23 46 0 48 0 1
E24 49 50 51 52 4.2E-3
I7 0 52 100E-6
D6 52 0 DVN
I8 0 51 100E-6
D7 51 0 DVN
R63 25 48 5
R64 49 27 5
Q33 25 25 53 QN
Q34 53 53 27 QN
Q35 54 54 25 QN
Q36 27 27 54 QN
E25 11 0 4 0 1
E26 8 0 7 0 1
I9 7 4 0.3E-3
R65 4 7 41.67E3
E27 18 0 8 11 0.001
C13 2 0 3E-12
C14 48 0 3E-12
C15 48 2 12E-12
V10 50 2 0
R66 12 15 1
R67 13 10 1
I13 48 0 -509.7E-9
I14 2 0 -509.7E-9
Q37 32 32 11 QN
I15 11 30 286E-6
D8 6 7 DOC
D9 4 6 DOC
.MODEL DD D
.MODEL DOC D RS=20
.MODEL DVN D KF=1.6E-13
.MODEL QN NPN
.MODEL QON NPN BF=15 RC=70
.MODEL QOP PNP BF=15 RC=95
.MODEL QIN NPN BF=270 KF=8E-17
.ENDS
```

You might be able to find this yourself if you look for the OPA227 in LTSpice - according to Analog Devices it is an available op-amp. Or you could press google a tad harder and find [this](http://waynestegall.com/audio/spice-models/OPA227.txt): -

```
*$
* BEGIN MODEL OPA227
* ------------------------------------------------------------------------
*|(C) Copyright Texas Instruments Incorporated 2007. All rights reserved. |
*|                                                                        |
*|This Model is designed as an aid for customers of Texas Instruments.    |
*|No warranties, either expressed or implied, with respect to this Model  |
*|or its fitness for a particular purpose is claimed by Texas Instruments |
*|or the author.  The Model is licensed solely on an "as is" basis.  The  |
*|entire risk as to its quality and performance is with the customer.     |
* ------------------------------------------------------------------------
* PINOUT        3   2   7  4  6
* PINOUT ORDER +IN -IN +V -V OUT
.SUBCKT OPA227 3 2 7 4 6
* FEATURES MODELED ARE
* OPEN LOOP GAIN AND PHASE
* INPUT VOLTAGE NOISE W 1/F
* INPUT CURRENT NOISE W 1/F
* INPUT BIAS CURRENT
* INPUT CAPACITANCE
* INPUT COMMON MODE VOLT RANGE
* INPUT DIFFERENTIAL CLAMPS
* CMRR WITH FREQUENCY EFFECTS
* PSRR WITH FREQUENCY EFFECTS
* SLEW RATE
* QUIESCENT CURRENT
* QUIESCENT CURRENT VS VOLTAGE
* OUTPUT CURRENT THROUGH SUPPLIES
* OUTPUT CURRENT LIMITING
* OUTPUT CLAMPS TO RAILS
* OUTPUT SWING VS OUTPUT CURRENT
* END OF FEATURES
Q26 8 9 10 QON
Q27 11 9 12 QOP
Q28 4 13 14 QOP
Q29 7 15 16 QON
I4 8 15 3E-3
I5 13 11 3E-3
R34 17 16 1
R35 14 17 1
C6 9 18 40E-12
R36 18 9 1E3
G1 9 18 19 0 -1E-3
G2 20 18 21 22 -0.5E-2
R37 18 20 1E10
C7 19 23 115E-12
R38 19 20 1.5E3
E1 24 18 19 18 1
D2 24 20 DD
R39 18 23 50
Q30 22 25 26 QIN
Q31 21 27 28 QIN
Q32 29 30 31 QN
R40 11 31 4.499E3
V6 30 32 1.2613
R41 22 33 220
R42 21 33 220
V7 8 34 2
R45 29 26 1
R46 29 28 1
R47 6 17 10
D1 34 33 DD
D3 20 24 DD
D4 35 8 DD
D5 11 36 DD
V8 35 20 1.6
V9 20 36 1.1
E6 37 0 8 0 1
E7 38 0 11 0 1
E8 39 0 40 0 1
R48 37 41 100E6
R49 38 42 100E6
R50 39 43 1000E6
R51 0 41 100
R52 0 42 100
R53 0 43 100
E11 44 3 43 0 0.7
R54 45 40 1E3
R55 40 46 1E3
C10 37 41 1E-9
C11 38 42 1E-9
C12 39 43 1E-12
E12 47 44 42 0 0.3
E13 48 47 41 0 0.3
R60 47 48 1E9
R61 44 47 1E9
R62 3 44 1E9
E22 45 0 2 0 1
E23 46 0 48 0 1
E24 49 50 51 52 4.2E-3
I7 0 52 100E-6
D6 52 0 DVN
I8 0 51 100E-6
D7 51 0 DVN
R63 25 48 5
R64 49 27 5
Q33 25 25 53 QN
Q34 53 53 27 QN
Q35 54 54 25 QN
Q36 27 27 54 QN
E25 11 0 4 0 1
E26 8 0 7 0 1
I9 7 4 0.3E-3
R65 4 7 41.67E3
E27 18 0 8 11 0.001
C13 2 0 3E-12
C14 48 0 3E-12
C15 48 2 12E-12
V10 50 2 0
R66 12 15 1
R67 13 10 1
I13 48 0 -509.7E-9
I14 2 0 -509.7E-9
Q37 32 32 11 QN
I15 11 30 286E-6
D8 6 7 DOC
D9 4 6 DOC
.MODEL DD D
.MODEL DOC D RS=20
.MODEL DVN D KF=1.6E-13
.MODEL QN NPN
.MODEL QON NPN BF=15 RC=70
.MODEL QOP PNP BF=15 RC=95
.MODEL QIN NPN BF=270 KF=8E-17
.ENDS
```

Comment: ak Thank you  but i can't find where i can download it
I need this in a folder

Comment: Copy the text from above to a text file and name the text file appropriately then, put the text file inside a folder and name the folder appropriately.

Comment: @marwa please take the [2 minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand how to give thanks in a better way. TYs are good but there is a more acceptable process (that is just as free).

Comment: Thank you  very much for your help

Comment: @marwa - did you take the 2 minute tour? Did you figure out how to close down this Q and A session?

Comment: I told you the last time thank you for your help what do you expect me to say?
if you don't want to help me, that's okay  .Thank you

Comment: Are you saying that you don't want to ever mark any answer as formally accepted? That is one of the main advantages on this site for people giving answers. Call it a form of payment that costs nothing @marwa. Of course you don't need to accept my answer and you don't need to ever accept any answers at all; folk will still advise you but that will dwindle off rapidly.

Comment: @marwa  Id you go to Andy's second example [here](http://waynestegall.com/audio/spice-models/OPA227.txt) you can save the file. In Windows use Ctrl-S. In other systems ?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon what do you mean?

Comment: @marwa [this link](http://waynestegall.com/audio/spice-models/OPA227.txt) which was provided by Andy there is a SPICE model that meets your neds. It can be downloaded in all the usual ways. It is for an OPA227 - the datasheet image provided by Andy shows than an OPA227 and OPA2227 are identical electrically - so it will suit your needs.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon okay thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Mouser had PSpice models for download but they went to a 404 error page. The last one they had was revision 'C' so I tried the link with a 'D' on the end and got a download.

Here is the working [download link](https://www.ti.com/litv/zip/sbom051d).

Comment: in this file there is OPAx227 is the same as OPA2227?

Comment: @marwa Yes, the OPA227 is a single amp package, OPA2227 is dual, OPA4227 is quad.

Comment: @marwa I'm not sure what you mean. You might want to ask that as a new question.

Comment: okay Thank you very much